# Resizable, hidable pane in XAML implemented as declaratively as possible

Tags: wpf, xaml

Using C#, XAML and WPF, I want to create a pane that expands from the bottom edge of the window, similar to the **pane for message content in many desktop e-mail clients**. I want to be able to hide it completely. It should be resizable by dragging the splitter between its content and the main content of the window.

I managed to implement it very declaratively, but it has a bug I cannot manage to fix without sacrificing the clarity of declarative implementation where code-behind focuses on supported operations and does not directly fiddle with state of used UI components.

- The whole layout is a three-row grid, where the middle row contains a `GridSplitter`.
- A dependency property named `PaneVisible` is two-way bound to visibilities of the `GridSplitter` and the `ContentControl` in the pane.
- When `PaneVisible == false`, the middle row collapses automatically as it has `Height` set to `Auto`. The `Height` of the bottom row is set to `0` via a `DataTrigger`.

When I just toggle the `PaneVisible` back and forth, it works as desired. **After I drag the `GridSplitter`, the last row is never collapsed anymore**, which is undesired. I know that `RowDefinition.Height` gets a local value and the values specified in style (including `DataTrigger`) are no longer used (overridden).

I thought about introducing another dependency property `PaneHeight` but I failed setting up the bindings so that when `PaneVisible == false`, the `RowDefinition.Height` is 0 and `PaneHeight` preserves the original value. Is setting its value imperatively the only option, or is there a declarative way to solve my problem?

<sup>Suggestions about the overall design are welcome, too. I have virtually no experience with UI programming.</sup>

---

The markup:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestingApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestingApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition MinHeight="20" Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition.Style>
          <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}, Path=PaneVisible}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </RowDefinition.Style>
      </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Click="TogglePane_Click">Toggle pane</ToggleButton>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}, Path=PaneVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Name="Pane" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}, Path=PaneVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
      <TextBlock>Yadayada</TextBlock>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

In `Application.Resources`, I added `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />`.

The code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTestingApplication
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PaneVisibleProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("PaneVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool PaneVisible
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(PaneVisibleProperty); }
      set { SetValue(PaneVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TogglePane_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      PaneVisible = !PaneVisible;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, as you already know, you need to reset the height somehow anyway. Even if there is a way, I guess it will be not easy to read.

If I were you, I would define `UserControl` for that purpose named like "SplitPanel". This SplitPanel has some properties for upper element, lower element and lower panel visibility. This SplitPanel will have only that logic on code behind. I expect it will be easy to implement and for future maintenance, and you can keep your main XAML and its code behind simple.